# Which major Java-based business rule engines have compatible rule languages?

Tags: java, rule-engine, business-rules

I am aware of several widely used business rules systems implemented in Java (e.g., [Jess](http://herzberg.ca.sandia.gov/), [ODM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r5/index.jsp)/JRules, [Drools](https://www.jboss.org/drools/)) and several proposed standards for representing business rules (e.g., Production Rule Representation ([PRR](http://www.omg.org/spec/PRR/)), Rule Interchange Format ([RIF](http://www.w3.org/2005/rules/wiki/RIF_Working_Group))).  We would like to have the possibility of changing from one business rule system to another without rewriting the business rules.  Which of the major business rule systems have compatibility with others, and using which formats?  Thus far, I'm not aware of any.  The rule formats I've seen are product-specific.

Comment: Preemptively, this is a question about the specific capabilities of different packages, not a request for recommendations.

Comment: The documentation of the engines is the place to find this.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to use rules from one engine in another or if there is the possibility of interoperability? The latter is definitely possible. Have you looked into IBM ILog?

Comment: @jjhavokk - I'm asking about instances where rules defined in one system can be used in another with little or no modification, although I am interested in hearing more regarding your comment about interoperability.  (I am looking at IBM's ODM, the ILog JRules successor).

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question to answer as it depends highly upon each product's support for the given standards as well as which features are being used in the specific engine you are migrating away from.

Are you actually trying to migrate from one system to another? Are you are trying to pick your initial system based on how easily it would be to migrate away from it?

Comment: I'm trying to pick my initial system with hopes for minimal disruption if we change our minds later.

Comment: I see. And I probably should have put this a comment, rather than an answer.